# How resolve 404 error in multipart file upload?

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I'm trying to implement a simple file upload function using AngularJs and Spring RESTful web services.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>File Upload Example</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myuploadfunction.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myAp">
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
            <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
                <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myAp', []);

myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = "upload";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

**REST**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {

        System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

When I run, I get this - POST http://localhost:8080/File/upload 404 (Not Found).
I'm following http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs  for script reference. Any help on this?

Comment: Is your Java handler mapped to `/upload` or `/file/upload` (like you're calling?) Do you have that prefix set up somewhere else?

Comment: @Antiga, As you can see, it is mapped to /upload in REST and it is mpped nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, I used MultipartFile as a @RequestParam not a @RequestBody
and the name should match the `<input>` tag's "name" attribute.

see http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/